# Does AngularJS always know when something has changed, it's time to update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading [AngularJS in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/angularjs-in-action) by ***Lukas Ruebbelke*** to clear the concept of dirty checking as to how AngularJS works at a molecular level.

The author puts forward,

> It is during the digest cycle that all watch expressions for a scope object
>   are evaluated. When a watch expression detects that a $scope property has 
>   changed, then a listener function is fired. 
>   Ocassionally a property is changed without AngularJS knowing about it. You
>   can manually kickstart a digest cycle vis $apply.

So, my question is  what are those situations in a real web application when I need to kick off this digest cycle manually. And are those situations often seen? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This will come up any time an asynchronous callback returns from a non-angular library. e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.myVar = 1;
    //Angular doesn't know when setTimeout finishes 
    //so you have to manually kick off a digest cycle.
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Angular has the `$timeout` service which takes care of starting a digest cycle for you but if you are using some third party library that takes a callback and doesn't have an angular wrapper then you will have to do this.

Comment: AngularJS doesn't know when setTimeout finishes, but there will be a definite moment when it does happen. Can you please shed some light as to how $digest will react in this case.

Answer (score 1):

These situations can happen when using 3rd party libraries which provide some kind of data for example.

Say you use library-X which fires an event when something happened and new data is available, which you would like to render with AngularJS.
In these causes AngularJS does not know that data in the scope changed if you just directly set the variables.

That is why you should only modify scope variables inside the $apply function:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.load = function() {
        $scope.message = 'Loading...';
        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.message = 'Finished loading!';
            });
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

It is also advised to use `$scope.$apply(function () { /* update code */ })` instead of the single `$scope.$apply()` call, since it will properly catch errors and run the diggest regardless of any errors.